How do I position my text beside my slideshow
I recently added a slideshow to my image, previously the layout enabled the image to be on the top left and the text in the text container would be on the right hand side, however now the text is on the bottom.
I have tinkered around with the CSS, used some AI tools and tried refactoring but cannot figure it out. I have no doubts it is something simple like it usually is but I would like to get it fixed as soon as possible.


.left {
  float: left;
}

.slide-show-container {
  max-width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.mySlides:first-of-type {
  display: block;
}

.image-text-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  float: left;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-right: 40%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.image-container {
  flex-basis: 40%;
  margin-right: 20%;
}

.image-container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.text-container {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 50%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.text-container p {
  margin: 10px, 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.photo-type {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
  left: auto;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
<div class="container-fluid" id="welcomeBar">
  <h1 id="homeTitle">Welcome to the Website</h1>
  <label id="date"></label>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="home">
  <h1 id="homeHeader">header</h1>
  <div class="image-text-container">
    <div class="slide-show-container">

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="image-container">
          <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
          <img src="photo1" class="photo-type" />
          <figcaption>text</figcaption>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="image-container">
          <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
          <img src="photo2" class="photo-type" />
          <figcaption>text</figcaption>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="image-container">
          <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
          <img src="photo3" class="photo-type" />
          <figcaption>text</figcaption>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮ PREV</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯ NEXT</a>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="text-container">
    <p>text here</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>




Have you validate your html code? i think you have some divs unclosed and for example you can't use figcaption in that way...

It was working fine before I added the slideshow

If you want any two divs infront of each other. you can use display flex or display grid.
Flex and Grid is easy way to deal with layouts like these.

You may have just confused the structure of the HTML. You have too many closing </div> tags and the .text-container is not inside the .image-text-container in your code as it probably should be. The following adjusted version displays the text to the right-hand-side of the .slide-show-container (which doesn't work here because I don't have the pictures and the JavaScript, you use for it). I made no changes to the CSS.


.left {
  float: left;
}

.slide-show-container {
  max-width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.mySlides:first-of-type {
  display: block;
}

.image-text-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  float: left;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-right: 40%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.image-container {
  flex-basis: 40%;
  margin-right: 20%;
}

.image-container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.text-container {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 50%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.text-container p {
  margin: 10px, 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.photo-type {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
  left: auto;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
<div class="container-fluid" id="welcomeBar">
    <h1 id="homeTitle">Welcome to the Website</h1>
    <label id="date"></label>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="home">
    <h1 id="homeHeader">header</h1>
    <div class="image-text-container">
        <div class="slide-show-container">

            <div class="mySlides">
                <div class="image-container">
                    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
                    <img src="photo1" class="photo-type" />
                    <figcaption>text</figcaption>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides">
                <div class="image-container">
                    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
                    <img src="photo2" class="photo-type" />
                    <figcaption>text</figcaption>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides">
                <div class="image-container">
                    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
                    <img src="photo3" class="photo-type" />
                    <figcaption>text</figcaption>
                </div>
            </div>

            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮ PREV</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯ NEXT</a>

        </div>
        <div class="text-container">
            <p>text here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




Fixed, thanks. Just have to fix the spacing of the text container, must have done this by accident.
